# R: trouble using XML to obtain data frame from html table

Tags: html, r

I am trying to get the data from the table at http://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekend/chart/?view=&yr=2015&wknd=09&p=.htm into a data frame. Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(XML)
data <- readHTMLTable('http://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekend/chart/?view=&yr=2015&wknd=09&p=.htm')
```

Not very familiar with the XML library, but I'm not sure how to get the data out of this. It's contained in 'data', but it's really ugly and I can't figure out how to use it. Any advice?

Comment: According to the `R` manual, `data` should contain a list of data frames or matrices.  Have you inspected the results yet?  Do you get any errors from the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page in browser you can see 46 rows and 12 columns in your html table. Inspect the result (your `data`) with `str` if something similar is included:

```
> str(data, max.level = 1)
List of 5
 $ NULL:'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ NULL: NULL
 $ NULL: NULL
 $ NULL:'data.frame':   49 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ NULL:'data.frame':   46 obs. of  12 variables:
```

The last table (no. 5) looks like your target. Your table is then:

```
my_table <- data[[5]]
```

You can specify the table number directly with `which` parameter:

```
my_table <- readHTMLTable('the url', which = 5)
```

Some rows and columns:

```
> head(my_table[,3:6])
                                        V3    V4          V5     V6
1                             Focus (2015)    WB $19,100,000      -
2             Kingsman: The Secret Service   Fox $11,750,000 -36.0%
3 The SpongeBob Movie: Sponge Out of Water  Par. $11,200,000 -32.4%
4                     Fifty Shades of Grey  Uni. $10,927,000 -50.9%
5                       The Lazarus Effect Rela. $10,600,000      -
6                           McFarland, USA    BV  $7,797,000 -29.3%
```

Answer (score 0):

Super-straightforward with `rvest`, too:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

pg <- html("http://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekend/chart/?view=&yr=2015&wknd=09&p=.htm")
pg %>% html_nodes("table") %>% extract2(5) %>% html_table()
```

The `magrittr` package is optional (I just prefer using it in pipelines). If you prefer non-pipe operations, you can forego `magrittr`/`extract2` and just:

```
library(rvest)
pg <- html("http://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekend/chart/?view=&yr=2015&wknd=09&p=.htm")
html_table(html_nodes(pg, "table")[[5]])
```